# Is there any better way to read a file line by line and search for specific words?

Tags: c, string, file, search

I've used this method to read a much smaller text file and it worked perfectly fine. My issue comes with reading [this](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/clickstream/2019-09/clickstream-enwiki-2019-09.tsv.gz) larger file (1.5G). The goal is to parse the file searching for whatever word the user enters and return the number of occurrences. Here's what I have so far.

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 5){
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 0;
    }

FILE *fpClick;
fpClick = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (!fpClick){
    printf("\nUnable to open file\n");
    return 0;
}

char *buffClick = NULL;
char *holderClick = NULL;
size_t lnSizeClick = 0;
char *foundFlagClick;
int foundCountClick = 0;
lnSizeClick = 0;
int glReturnClick = 0;

while (1){
    glReturnClick = getline(&buffClick, &lnSizeClick,fpClick);
    holderClick = buffClick;
    if (glReturnClick < 0){
        break;
    }
    
    foundFlagClick = strstr(holderClick, argv[2]);
    if (foundFlagClick){
        foundCountClick++;
    }
    
    
}

free(buffClick);

printf("%s Count: %d\n", argv[2], foundCountClick);

fclose(fpClick);
}
```

So my question is am I going about this wrong? Is there possibly a memory issue? The output i'm receiving is 387006 occurrences of the word "football" when the expected output is 452566 occurrences.

```
input - ./progName fileToSearch wordToSearch
output(printed to terminal) - wordToSearch was found x times
```

Comment: you need to check for errors in closing the file. also, after you free buffclick you don't need to set it to be null

Comment: @AndreasWenzel hopefully the most recent edit cleared things up. Also, the file is unzipped.

Comment: @MikeQuinnn: Yes, it has, that is why I have deleted my comments.

Comment: I suggest that you print out the entire line whenever a match occurrs. This should help you understand what is going on.

Comment: Note that the function `strstr` will also match words such as "footballs". Maybe that is the reason for the discrepancy? Actually, that doesn't explain it, because that should lead to too many words being reported, but you say that it is reporting too little words.

Comment: Your program will only count the number of lines containing the word. It won't count how many times that word occurs on the line. So if the word occurs twice on the same line, it will only be counted once.

Comment: Another possible issue is that your program won't count hyphenated words. If the word `foot-` occurs on one line with a hyphen, and the rest of the word `ball` occurs in the next line, then your program won't detect the word.

Comment: I see. So strstr() will only be true on the first occurrence in a line? I'm thinking the best route to go would to be only searching the entire line if strstr() is true, therefor I won't slow down the program as much.

Comment: I believe it would be sufficient to write the following: `for ( const char *p = buffClick; p = strstr( p, argv[2] ); p += strlen( argv[2] ) ) foundCountClick++;` This will always call `strstr` until it returns `NULL`. However, it would be better for `strlen( argv[2] )` to be precalculated once and stored in a variable, so that it does not have to be recalculated in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons for the discrepancy:

1. Your program will only count the number of lines containing the word. It won't count how many times that word occurs on the line. So if the word occurs twice on the same line, it will only be counted once.
2. When searching for `football`, the function `strstr` will also match `footballs`, not just `football`.
3. When searching for `football`, the function `strstr` will **not** match `Football` (e.g. when the word is at the start of a sentence), because the function is case-sensitive.
4. Your program won't count hyphenated words. If the word `foot-` occurs on one line with a hyphen, and the rest of the word `ball` occurs in the next line, then your program won't detect the word.

In order to solve problem #1, you can change the lines

```
foundFlagClick = strstr(holderClick, argv[2]);
if (foundFlagClick){
    foundCountClick++;
}
```

to the following:

```
size_t word_len = strlen( argv[2] );

for ( const char *p = holderClick; p = strstr( p, argv[2] ); p += word_len )
    foundCountClick++;
```

This will call `strstr` until it returns `NULL`.

Or, if this code is too compact for you, you can also write it more verbose:

```
size_t word_len = strlen( argv[2] );
const char *p = holderClick;

while ( ( p = strstr( p, argv[2] ) != NULL )
{
    foundCountClick++

    p += word_len;
}
```

In order to solve problem #2, you would have to compare one word at a time using `strcmp`, instead of searching a whole line at a time using `strstr`.

In order to solve problem #3, you would have to either write your own compare function that performs a case-insensitive compare, or use a platform-specific function which already offers this feature, such as [`strcasecmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcasecmp.3p.html) on POSIX platforms or [`_stricmp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l?view=msvc-170) on Micrsoft Visual C++.

In order to solve problem #4, you would have to remember whether the previous line contained a hyphenated word and then merge it into a whole word when reading the next line.